# nslookup/dig/drill commands on a file that contains websites to add ip addresses

Tags: shell, awk, sed, nslookup, dig

**UPDATE** : Still open for solutions using `nslookup without parallel`, `dig` or `drill`

I need to write a script that scans a file containing web page addresses on each line, and adds to these lines the IP address corresponding to the name using `nslookup` command. The script looks like this at the moment :

```
#!/usr/bin/

while read ip
do

   nslookup "$ip" | 
   awk '/Name:/{val=$NF;flag=1;next} /Address:/ &&
        flag{print val,$NF;val=""}' | 
   sed -n 'p;n'

done < is8.input
```

The input file contains the following websites :

```
www.edu.ro
vega.unitbv.ro

www.wikipedia.org
```

The final output should look like :

```
www.edu.ro 193.169.21.181
vega.unitbv.ro 193.254.231.35

www.wikipedia.org 91.198.174.192
```

The main problem i have with the current state of the script is that it takes the names from `nslookup` (which is good for www.edu.ro) instead of taking the aliases when those are available. My output looks like this:

```
www.edu.ro 193.169.21.181
etc.unitbv.ro 193.254.231.35

dyna.wikimedia.org 91.198.174.192
```

I was thinking about implementing a `if-else` for aliases but i don't know how to do one on the current command. Also the script can be changed if anyone has a better understanding of how to format nslookup to show it like the output given.

Comment: Btw.: Fix your shebang.

Answer (score 2):

Minimalist workaround quasi-answer.  Here's a one-liner replacement for the script using *GNU* `parallel`, `host` (less work to parse than `nslookup`), and `sed`:

```
parallel "host {} 2> /dev/null | 
          sed -n '/ has address /{s/.* /'{}' /p;q}'" < is8.input
```

...or using `nslookup` at the cost of added *GNU* `sed` complexity.

```
parallel "nslookup {} 2> /dev/null | 
          sed -n '/^A/{s/.* /'{}' /;T;p;q;}'"  < is8.input
```

...or using `xargs`:

```
xargs -I '{}' sh -c \
         "nslookup {}  2> /dev/null | 
          sed -n '/^A/{s/.* /'{}' /;T;p;q;}'"  < is8.input
```

Output of any of those:

```
www.edu.ro 193.169.21.181
vega.unitbv.ro 193.254.231.35
www.wikipedia.org 208.80.154.224
```

Comment: [*Potong*'s `sed` & `host` one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60913759/6136214) is a better and simpler version of the above.

Comment: Really good command but is it possible to work it around without parallel ? @agc

Answer (score 1):

Replace your complete `nslookup` line with:

```
echo "$IP $(dig +short "$IP" | grep -m 1 -E '^[0-9.]{7,15}$')"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and host):

```
sed '/\S/{s#.*#host & | sed -n "/ has address/{s///p;q}"#e}' file
```

For all non-empty lines: invoke the host command on the supplied host name and pipe the results to another invocation of sed which strips out text and quits after the first result.

Comment: This is better.  Hadn't though of using ***`e`***_val_ instead of `parallel`.

Comment: @agc I'm all for using GNU parallel but in this case it seems the OP wants to preserve empty lines and sed seemed a better fit in this circumstance.